# char в hex на delphi

Tags: delphi, перекодировка

У нас есть поток данных с железяки, принимаем их в видел символов, необходимо перевести все это дело в hex для дальнейшей работы с ними, есть свой вариант перевода но он не работает как надо 
Код:

```
function StrToHex(source: String): String;
var i:integer;
c:Char;
s:String;
begin
s := '';
for i:=1 to Length(source) do
begin
  c := source[i];
  s := s +  IntToHex(Integer(c),1)+' ';
end;
result := s;
end;
```

то есть, срабатывает как надо в большинстве случаев, но некоторые символы кодируются не правильно например 
символ "▐" должен кодироваться как "DE", но мы получаем результат "A".
в чем проблема и как это исправить??

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно это вам необходимо делать? С одной стороны ведь железяка, вы собираете с нее информацию, а затем переводите в строку.

Если же, например, дальнейшая обработка данных будет тоже программная, то зачем вам HEX?

Простите, конечно, если вам нужно смотреть на данные с железяки в HEX, но имхо это просто набор 16-ричных символов. В таком случае как вы определили, как должен кодироваться необходимый вам символ?

Comment: символ определи путем ручной перекодировки символов по таблицам, символ взяли из расширенной таблицы символов, да дальнейшая обработка будет выполнятся последующими функциями(которые уже прекрасно работают но из за не совсем корректного перевода из char в hex вылезают обидные ошибки), а преобразование из char в hex делаем потому что пока что не знаем прямого пути из char в dec

Comment: Ord(A); //где A - это ваш char

Хотя я по-прежнему не понимаю разницы между потоком байт и вашими char-ами.

Comment: тут проблема в том что человек с которым я работаю, написал подключение к железяке через bcompotr и на выходе мне дается строка, и я теряюсь что мне делать, функция ord говорит что неподходящий тип переменной у меня тк str, в х-ке функции есть тип int если я переведу свою строку в int, ord сработает как надо?

Comment: Строка состоит из массива байт (char). Т.е. по большому счету это уже есть и dec и hex и прочие. Имея на входе строку преобразовывать ее к строке, но в виде hex какой в этом смысл, когда, например вы можете строку превратить в `array of byte` и потом уже вертеть как хотите, если уж `String` вам не нравится?

Comment: можно подробней, просто не много не понимаю сути перевода в байты? просто исходный string у меня например такой "„»" а после 3х функций strtohex потом первую пару символов с последней (не помню как называется правильно) и потом уже hextofloat и на выходе "48004", в каком направлении мыслить мне если мой путь не правельный

Comment: Любая последовательность байт может быть преобразована во что угодно. Если вам нужно на выходе получить float то сразу и преобразовывайте в него, а не занимайтесь велосипедостроением.

Comment: в том то и дело что я не понимаю как делать правильно, а делаю всякий бред который вроде как работает но при этом глючит периодически

Comment: @Bob ord -- функция, чей аргумент должен иметь тип "перечисление". ord(byte) -- результат скрещивания паскаля с действительностью

Answer (score 1):

```
IntToHex(Integer(c),1)
```

Даст вам 1 символ. Чтобы получить 2 (DE) пишите:

```
IntToHex(Integer(c),2)
```